# In Azure Cognitive Search skillsets can I default a value for a Collection(Edm.Double)?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I'm using the v10 SDK (Microsoft.Azure.Search) to build a skillset. I have an index that contains a field for money defined as a Collection of Edm.Double. This will hold all monetary values found in the document.

When there are monetary values, everything works well.

When there are no monetary values in the document, the value will be null and the outputmappings given a warning:

> Could not map output field 'money' to search index. Check the 'outputFieldMappings' property of your indexer.

It is only a warning, but it does fill up the logs ;-)

Here is the C# code I've tried to default the value (following example2 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-conditional#sample-skill-definition-2-set-a-default-value-for-a-value-that-doesnt-exist))

```
_skillset.Skills.Add(new ConditionalSkill {
  Context = "/document/pages/*",
  Inputs = new List<InputFieldMappingEntry> {
    new InputFieldMappingEntry("condition", "= $(/document/pages/*/output_money) == null"),
    new InputFieldMappingEntry("whenTrue", "= []"),
    new InputFieldMappingEntry("whenFalse", "/document/pages/*/output_money"),
  },
  Outputs = new List<OutputFieldMappingEntry> {
    new OutputFieldMappingEntry("output", "money")
  }
});
```

When I try this, I get an error:

```
Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: One or more skills are invalid. Details: Input 'whenTrue' source is an invalid expression (= []): Parsing failure: unexpected 
'['; expected ConditionalLevel (Line 1, Column 3); recently consumed: = 
   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.SkillsetsOperations.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(String skillsetName, Skillset skillset, SearchRequestOptions searchRequestOptions, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Search.SkillsetsOperationsExtensions.CreateOrUpdateAsync(ISkillsetsOperations operations, Skillset skillset, SearchRequestOptions searchRequestOptions, AccessCondition accessCondition, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Elastacloud.KnowledgeMiner.Standalone.App.Program.Setup(IConfigurationRoot conf) in C:\src\km-standalone\src\Program.cs:line 61
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
```

Comment: The error message means the inputs don't support the empty array literal value [], but is that what you intended? It seems strange to default a missing number to an empty array.
What's your desired output for "money" if the 1st page is missing output_money and the 2nd page had output_money=2?

Comment: Thanks, the desire is really to get rid of the warning. To do that, a value needs to be provided before outputMappings are calculated. My thought is to achieve this using an empty array [] since there is no other valid value.

Comment: You can try to assemble the whole array for "money" before output field mappings, so it'll always have a previously defined value to use, but that might push the warnings upstream to the skill that generates "money".

context: "/document"
input: "=$(/document/pages/*/output_money)"

If that fails then you can add a suggestion here: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search